# What is wrong with my code, i been trying to figure it out for hours?

Tags: python, tkinter

my program is meant say 'Accessed granted' if i enter the correct username and password, however regardless of what i type, i keep getting 'Invalid login' can someone point out whats wrong? btw dont worry about it the indentation is wrong, it changes when it put code on this site.

```
from tkinter import *# Ingress all components from Tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox as box

def dialog1():

    username=entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    if (username == 'admin' and  password == 'ad121'):#Correct log in details
        box.showinfo('info','Access granted')# correct response
    else:
        box.showinfo('info','Invalid Login')# decline response

def condition():
     while condition == (username == 'admin' and  password == 'ad121'): 
      print = label(text('Welcome back admin user!',bg='Light Blue',font='none 14 bold').place(x=0,y=160))


window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')# The size of the form window
window.title('Office login system')#title of the form

frame = Frame(window)

mlabel = Label(text='Log in system', bg='Light Blue',font='none 18 bold underline')# The colours and font style and size used for the form title
mlabel.pack()

Label1 = Label(window,text = 'Username:',bg='Light Blue',font='none 14 bold').place(x=0,y=100)
entry2 = Entry(window).place(x=140,y=108)#Size and colour of the text box


entry1 = Entry(window,bd =5)
entry1.pack

Label2 = Label(window,text = 'Password:',bg='Light Blue',font='none 14 bold').place(x=0,y=150)
entry2 = Entry(window).place(x=140,y=155)#Size and colour of the text box


entry2 = Entry(window, bd=5)
entry2.pack


window.configure(background='Orange')

btn = Button(window, text = 'Check Login',command = dialog1)


btn.place(x=150,y=250)
frame.pack(padx =200,pady =190)


window.mainloop()# The code iterates
```

Comment: i know my spelling and grammar is bad, i didn't proof read it

Comment: can you print username and password before your if condition? what does it show?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by that?

Comment: ... after you've set the variables `username` and `password` do `print(username)` and `print(password)` so that you can check they really contain the words "admin" and "ad121".

Comment: first step : check and clean all the `entry2`, you are making multiple declarations. Then you should not use `entry2 = Entry(window).place(x=140,y=155)` in one line, because you obtain the result of the method `place` -->  `None`

Comment: i get just did that got the same response

Comment: still getting the wrong answer with the correct answer

Comment: what do you see in the console with `print('password : ' + password)` ?

Comment: when i run the program, the password entry box disappears.

Comment: try with `entry1 = Entry(window)` then `entry1.place(x=140,y=108)`

Comment: i got it to work using my own configuration, but now i have four answer boxes, and two of them actually give the right response. How do i fix this four box problem.

Comment: i added this: entry1 = Entry(window,bd =5)
entry1.pack(padx=15, pady=5)

Comment: and this:entry2 = Entry(window, bd=5)
entry2.pack(padx = 15,pady=7)

Comment: why are you keeping multiple declarations of `entry1` and `entry2` ?

Comment: i want to remove the first two, however they are postioned in the exact right location on the form, i am trying to move this location to the new entrys, if do that and delete the old one, there is a error and it only displays the username entry and not submit button.

Comment: Here is the new code - https://pastebin.com/8vm4jgyK

Comment: if the first ones are in the right place, keep them, but don't create and `place` them in the same line. you got some advices here, please try to apply some

Comment: No the first ones are in the right location, but they do not allow me to get the right response if i enter the correct answers. But with the new ones they give the right responses, only problem is i cant put it in the right location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `entry2` multiple times in the scope of your script.

I tried this and it works as you expect.

```
from tkinter import Button, Entry, Tk
import tkinter.messagebox as box

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.username_field = Entry(self.root)
        self.password_field = Entry(self.root)

        self.username_field.insert(0, "Enter Username")
        self.password_field.insert(0, "Enter Password")

        self.submit = Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=self.login)

        self.username_field.pack()
        self.password_field.pack()
        self.submit.pack()

    def login(self):
        username = self.username_field.get()
        password = self.password_field.get()

        print(username, password)

        # The while loop
        while username == password:
            box.showinfo("info", "Username and password must not match!")
            break

        if(username == "admin" and password == "ad121"):
            box.showinfo("info", "Welcome " + username + "!")
        else:
            box.showinfo("info", "Invalid credentials")

app = GUI()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: my assignment requires me to include at least, one if statement and while loop, is it possible to add it in somehow?

Comment: It already contains an `if` statement. Why would you need a `while` loop for this? It isn't needed here.

Comment: Ah i see the if statement now, i just one have to include one while loop and it should have some level role in the program.

Comment: You could **technically** do a `while username == password: box.showinfo("info", "Username must not match password!")` and then `break`
after the `print(username, password)` which would stop the user from entering the same value for username and password. I will edit my answer to do so.

Comment: You're welcome, If this answer helped you, please click the check mark button beside my answer to accept it as the solution.